Analytic function with values in $L^1$
Suppose that $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a measure space.
Let $D$ be the unit open disk and $F : D \rightarrow L^1(\mu)$ be an analytic function. Is it true that for a.e. $w \in \Omega$ the function $F(\cdot)(w) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic? Do we need to impose some condition on the measure space to obtain that?

An analytic function on the unit open disk has a power series expansion $F(z)=\sum_n f_n z^n$ with radius of convergence at least $1$. Once one chooses representatives $g_n$ of $f_n \in L^1$, it makes sense of speaking $F(z)(\omega)=\sum_n g_n(\omega)z^n$. One checks the radius of convergence of $F(,\cdot,)(\omega)$ is at least $1$ for a.e. $\omega\in\Omega$.

This does not quite make sense, because $L^1$ is a space of equivalence classes of functions for equality almost everywhere, and pointwise evaluation is not defined.  So you could have cases such as this.  Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be Lebesgue measure on $D$, and $F(z) = 0$ (as a member of $L^1$) for all $z$. This is certainly analytic. But if you happen to choose for $F(z)$ the particular representative $g_z(w)$ of the equivalence class that is $1$ when $w - z \in 
\mathbb Q + i \mathbb Q$ and $0$ everywhere else (where $\mathbb Q$ is the rationals), $F(\cdot)(w)$ is nowhere continuous.

Isn't the question basically asking whether a representative of $F \in L^1(D \times \Omega)$ exists which is analytic in the first variable everywhere? Seems reasonabke and also like standard theory should cover it. I don't remember though.
